# How to run a console application on a different pc?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am new at programming. I got a **little** console application Made with visual studio. But now I have done it, I want to run it on a different pc. Does somebody know how to do that? And what the requirements are for the pc?

Comment: when you compile your application it will end up in the bin\Debug or the bin\Release folder. Copy this entire content to the other computer and run the *.exe file.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do that the second I get to!

Comment: What framework does the application use?  .NET Core?

Comment: As for the PC itself it depends on whether you target .NET Framework or .NET Core. .NET Framework is built in on all current supported Windows, and .NET Core apps can be published with all the requisites in a folder

Comment: @Kirill yes I use .net

Comment: .NET may be older .NET Framework or modern .NET Core. For .NET Core you [want](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) to use command `dotnet publish -c Release` from directory with .sln file.  It will literally "[publish](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)" the app to the "bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\" directory which you can copy to another machine. .NET Core runtime should be installed on the machine where the application will run. Also you can tell publish to make self-contained version but it will increase the size.